# npm start can't find anything with Angular v2

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to run the below from the  [Angular 2 quickstart guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

I have to say what a terrible error.  What is the below translated to english?   I did run npm install.   using "npm run lite" does work howerver.

```
npm start

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start /home/ubuntu/workspace/bootopsnjs
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 

node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(39,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(99,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(174,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(26,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(105,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(105,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(70,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(8,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(12,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(62,148): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(103,144): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(108,139): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(109,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(28,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(30,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(32,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(34,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(36,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/testability/testability.d.ts(40,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.45
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/bootopsnjs/npm-debug.log
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/workspace/bootopsnjs$
```

Comment: did you configure [`typings`](https://github.com/typings/typings)? These errors come from `typescript` trying to figure out some symbols that it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm run postinstall
```

before `npm start` run the above command, it will install the TypeScript definition files defined in typings.json. If you are following the angualjs 2 quickstart guide.